# Saving partitioned table with BigQuery Spark connector

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery

I wanted to create a table using from pyspark with the below two options (partition by and require filter) but I can't see an option to do this with the BigQuery connector

This is how I would do it in BigQuery

```sql
CREATE dataset.table AS SELECT XXXX 
PARTITION BY
  DATE_TRUNC(collection_date, DAY) OPTIONS ( require_partition_filter = TRUE)
```

This is what I normally do

```py
dataframe
    .write
    .format("bigquery")
    .mode(mode)
    .save(f"{dataset}.{table_name}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `partitionField`, `datePartition`, `partitionType`

For Clustering use - `clusteredFields`

See more options:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector#properties